# Why am I loosing .obj texture when loading the model in aframe?

Tags: blender, maya, aframe

I've created a model in Maya and then exported it as a `.obj` file. Maya created both the `.obj` and `.mtl` files, but it doesn't make a reference to the texture image inside the `.mtl` file so I added it manually at the end of the file like this:

`map_Kd paht/to/texture_image/texture_image.png`

When I import the `.obj` model into blender for testing it looks like this:

[How the `.obj` looks when I open it in Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjKfM.png)

Apparenly it looks like that because Blender opens it in **Solid mode**, so when I change to **Texture mode** I can actually see my texture:

[How the `.obj` looks when I change to **Texture mode**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkpDk.png)

When I load the `.obj` inside an **aframe** project it looks exactly as it does in **Solid mode** (which is not what I want).

(I can't post a third image link but trust me, inside aframe it looks exactly as it does in blender solid mode, which is completely black)

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I'm loading the `.obj` model in aframe exactly as I do with other models that are loading correctly, just like this:

`<a-entity position = '0 0 -5' obj-model = "obj: url(path/to/file/model.obj); mtl: url(path/to/file/model.mtl)"></a-entity>`

I even make sure my `.mtl` file is correclty referencing the `.png` image I use as texture.

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

1. Create a 3d model in Maya
2. Export the model as `.obj`
3. Manually add the texture_image reference to the `.mtl` generated file
4. Import the `.obj` file into Blender and change to **Texture mode** to make sure the texture loads just fine
5. Load the `.obj` file inside an aframe page

**OBSERVATIONS**

I'm using a Windows 10 PC and here I use Maya 2017 and Blender 2.78. And for the aframe project I'm using macOS Sierra.

Comment: The [troubleshooting section](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/introduction/models.html#troubleshooting) in A-Frame's documentation is the best we can offer as general advice. If that doesn't help, I think you would need to provide an example model here. The steps you describe are correct.

Comment: thanks man, your [article](https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/06/27/exporting-gltf-2-0-from-maya-lt-2/) was really helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've stumbled upon two issues: 
1) incorrect paths in the .mtl file 
2) The material with the textures had the diffuse (kd) color set to black, which I had to manually change `0 0 0` -> `1 1 1` (in the .mtl file)

You can see a .obj + .mtl glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-objmtl?path=index.html:9:44).

---

Nonetheless I had some bad experience using aframe with 'standard' formats, as .obj, with their .mtl's.
I can only say models work with a-frame almost flawlessly, when converted to:

- .glTF ( khronos group has a really simple [exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF#converters-and-exporters) for blender ),
- and three.js .JSON ( using [clara.io](http://clara.io), ).

I had no trouble using those with Don McCurdy's [loaders](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders).

Comment: thanks for your answer Piotr, I have found a work around by converting to from .FBX to .MTL using [Autodesk FBX converter] (http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=22694909)